# How to draw an offset border to a tikz node?

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, arrows, tikz-arrows, border

How do I make an offset border like shown in the attached picture. This looks like it should be done with tikz pretty easily. I can use the "double" option for the node, but I have no idea how to continue for the attachment of the arrow(s).

[image: Example for an offset border]

Addition:

In the meantime, I got the following result:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,decorations.markings,arrows}

\begin{document}

\tikzstyle{border_arrow} = [%
  decoration={markings,mark=at position 1 with {\arrow[scale=2,line width=.25pt,red!50]{open triangle 60}}}, %
  red!50, double distance=4.4pt, shorten >= 9.5pt, shorten <= .45mm, %
line width=.5pt, %
  preaction = {decorate}, %
  postaction = {draw,line width=4.4pt, white,shorten >= 8.5pt, shorten <= 1pt}]
\tikzstyle{my_node} = [double,double distance=1mm, inner sep=3mm, text width=2.5cm, align=center,line width=.5pt,font=\sffamily\footnotesize\color{white},draw=red!50, fill=red!50]

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (data1) [my_node] {Commercial Starting Material};
\node [right=of data1] (A) {}; % phantom node to avoid overlapping
\draw[border_arrow] (data1.east|-A.west) -- (A.west);
\node (data2) [right of=A, my_node,xshift=.6cm] {A $\to$ B $\to$ C $\to$ D};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

If someone has a more simple way to achieve a similar result, I'm glad to hear it.

Comment: Please convert your code snipped to complete small document (MWE: Minimal Working Example), which will contain all necessary packages and yours definitions. How it is, can not be compiled. Help us too help you.

Comment: I changed it to a MWE, thanks for the advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I try to reproduce yours provided image:

[image]

My code is written from scratch::

```
\documentclass[tikz,
                border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,
                fit,
                positioning,
                shapes}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
 node distance = 0mm and 12mm,
 databox/.style = {inner sep=3mm, text width=2.4cm, align=center, fill=red,
                   font=\sffamily\footnotesize\bfseries\color{white}
                   },
arrowbox/.style = {arrow box, arrow box  arrows={east:12mm},
                   arrow box shaft width=5mm, arrow box head extend=3mm,
                   draw=red, very thick, inner sep=3mm
                   }
                    ]
\node (data1)   [databox]   {Commercial Starting Material};
\node (A1)      [arrowbox, fit=(data1)] {};
%
\node (data2)   [databox, right=of A1.east]
                            {A $\to$ B $\to$ C $\to$ D};
\node (A2)      [arrowbox, fit=(data2)] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative solution based on a `matrix` node which has `arrowbox` style and contains a `databox` node.

I thought that a `matrix` node was always rectangular, but now I know it can take whatever `shape` we want. The matrix only arranges inner nodes.

Based in [Zarko's code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/334480/1952):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, shapes}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
     node distance = 0mm and 12mm,
     databox/.style = {rectangle, %<---- added
                   inner sep=3mm, text width=2.4cm,  
                   align=center, fill=red,
                   font=\sffamily\footnotesize\bfseries\color{white}
                   },
     arrowbox/.style = {arrow box, arrow box  arrows={east:12mm},
                   arrow box shaft width=5mm, arrow box head extend=3mm,
                   draw=red, very thick, inner sep=3mm,
                   minimum width=36mm, minimum height=15mm
                   }
                    ]
\matrix[arrowbox] (A1) {\node[databox] {Commercial Starting Material};\\};
\matrix[arrowbox, right=of A1.east] (A1) {%
      \node[databox] {A $\to$ B $\to$ C $\to$ D};\\};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]